# jQuery breaks links when using slideToggle on mobile nav

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, mobile, slidetoggle

I am making a mobile nav menu on my WordPress site. I successfully created the dropdowns and the slide toggle works fine but in the submenus the links are broken. When you click on them nothing happens. In the inspector it has the correct link reference but just won't go on click. On desktop the links work fine.

Below is my jQuery:

```
jQuery('#menu-main-menu-1 > .menu-item-has-children > .sub-menu').addClass('first-sub');
    jQuery('#menu-main-menu-1 .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children .sub-menu').addClass('last-sub');

    jQuery('#menu-main-menu-1 > .menu-item-has-children a').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).siblings('.first-sub').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });

    jQuery('#menu-main-menu-1 > .menu-item-has-children > .first-sub > .menu-item-has-children a').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).siblings('.last-sub').slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
```

Below is my HTML code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main Menu' )); ?>
```

which translates into an HTML menu with the structure:

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="link1">page1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children"><a href="#">dropdown1</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu first-sub">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link2">page2</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link3">page3</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link4">page4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="link5">page5</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="link6">page6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `z-index`? maybe another item is on top of your link, `z-index` only works with a `position` property

Comment: I see no `.menu-item-has-children`, but the problem is that you return false on click on every `a` inside `.menu-item-has-children`. Assuming that class is on the `.menu-item` element. It might be better to do `.menu-item-has-children > a`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon sorry, i deleted all the extra classes to make it easier to read. the second item does in fact have the menu-item has children. I will try your suggestion and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: @theblackgigant i think that the z-index issue is fine because the cursor changes to pointer when hovering over the link

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon the solution was simple. i just needed to remove the "return false" on both instances. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with help from Karl-André Gagnon. All I had to do was remove the "return false".